# sql counting the number is not working correctly

Tags: sql

I make related queries and the counting does not work correctly, when I connect 4 and join and add a condition, it does not count correctly, but without the 4th joina and the condition it works correctly. first option result = 2

```
 SELECT
    pxixolog_details.*,
    directions.direction,
    COUNT(directions.direction)  procent
FROM
    pxixolog_details
LEFT JOIN psixologs_direction ON pxixolog_details.id = psixologs_direction.psixolog_id
LEFT JOIN directions ON directions.id = psixologs_direction.direction_id
LEFT JOIN psixologs_weeks ON pxixolog_details.id = psixologs_weeks.psixolog_id

WHERE
    directions.direction IN(
        'Трудности в отношениях',
        'Проблемы со сном',
        'Нежелательная агрессия'
    ) 
    AND birthday BETWEEN '1956-04-29' AND '2021-04-29' AND psixologs_weeks.week = '4'
    
GROUP BY
    pxixolog_details.id
```

and the second one doesn't work correctly. result = 4

```
SELECT
    pxixolog_details.*,
    directions.direction,
    COUNT(directions.direction)  procent
FROM
    pxixolog_details
LEFT JOIN psixologs_direction ON pxixolog_details.id = psixologs_direction.psixolog_id
LEFT JOIN directions ON directions.id = psixologs_direction.direction_id
LEFT JOIN psixologs_weeks ON pxixolog_details.id = psixologs_weeks.psixolog_id
LEFT JOIN psixologs_times ON pxixolog_details.id = psixologs_times.psixolog_id
WHERE
    directions.direction IN(
        'Трудности в отношениях',
        'Проблемы со сном',
        'Нежелательная агрессия'
    ) 
    AND birthday BETWEEN '1956-04-29' AND '2021-04-29' AND psixologs_weeks.week = '4'
    AND (psixologs_times.time = '09:00' OR psixologs_times.time = '10:00')
GROUP BY
    pxixolog_details.id
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why have you tagged PHP, MySQLi *and* SQL Server? What does the question have to do with PHP when there's nothing about PHP in the question? Why tag MySQLi, which is an API for MySQL, if you're using SQL Server? Neither of those queries (in SQL Server) will work, you are using `*` in your `SELECT`, yet only one column is in your `GROUP BY`. If you're using MySQL, it will *probably* work but you should be explicitly defining your `GROUP BY` clause. I have removed all the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question and tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You get double the amount of results when doing 4 `JOINs` because through the new (4th) `JOIN` you allow 2 records (9:00 and 10:00 o'clock) for each of the other joined records in the first 3 `JOINs`. That can lead to the observed result.

Check your data and make sure that your 4th `JOIN` condition yields a 1:1 record matching with the other data.

Answer (score 0):

The last table has `psixologs_times` matches multiple rows for each `psixolog_id`.

You can easily see this using a query:

```
select psixolog_id, count(*)
from psixologs_times
group by psixolog_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

How you fix this problem depends on what you want to do.  The simplest solution is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT directions.direction) as procent
```

However, this might just be hiding the problem.  You might want to choose one row from the `psixologs_times` table.  Or pre-aggregate it.  Or do something else.

Comment: Your version worked, but I want to explain in detail about  Or pre-aggregate it